# How to show menu pages?

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views

I build my first drupal site, and install corporate clean template that has nice drop down menu that i like.

Testing site:
http://hostingindia123.com

If someone click on menu link instead of following drop down to their desired page it will load blank node page that i set it to "node". Whereas I want if someone click on parents link then i want new page to load showing all the child taxonomy terms or node pages under it.

For ex: If someone click on our school then that page should display History as a link in that page, similarly the history is having sub-menu items when someone clicks on the history it should display the sub-menu items as links the History page, i heard that this can be done by using VIEWS, but i didn't know how can i do that...

Is it possible???

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are speaking of two different scenarios.  One with the sub pages shown, and one with the taxonomy shown.  Here are the modules you need below to achieve both of these scenarios.

This will help you add **subpages** of the current page to a block:
Menu Block - http://drupal.org/project/menu_block

This will help add a **taxonomy menu** to a block:
Taxonomy Menu - http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu